# Use calculated php variable to rotate a class item in css

Tags: php, css

I am having troubles to transfer my calculated php variable (which gives an output form -90 --> 90) to my css bar class (for a gauge). All the code is defined in the same php file

I want to do it with te following :
`.bar { position: absolute; width: 50%; height: 100%; background-color: var(--black); transform: rotate(<?php echo $degree; ?>deg)>;`

Tis is inside the style element. The value of degree is calculated below the style element inside a p element.

Could anybody help me

Comment: Right-click, view source (don't inspect) and look at what is being actually spit out, and then edit your question with that if you have any questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to calculate the value of $degree first, then assign it to rotate.

Comment: _"The value of degree is calculated below the style element"_ - if I told you that I wanted you to write a specific word onto the wall today, but that I will only tell you what that word actually is, tomorrow - do you think you'd be able to perform this task then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you truly are "calculating it below", then CSS custom properties still work perfectly with this, you just use the value in your style, optionally with a default value, and then set the custom property value in the `style` attribute on the tag itself:

```
<style>
    .bar {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: rotate(var(--local-bar-transform, 0));
    }
</style>

<?php
$degree = -10;
?>

<p class="bar" style="--local-bar-transform: <?php echo $degree; ?>deg">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/rNrgQoK

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a separate stylesheet with the dynamic value and then include it in your HTML.

**style.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$dynamicValue = ''; // Dynamic value of $degree
?>
.bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--black);
  transform: rotate(<?php echo $dynamicValue; ?>deg);
}
```

Then you need to include this stylesheet using the link element, like this.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.php">
</head>
```